# Spark: How to convert array of objects with fields key-value into columns with keys as names

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a column that contains array of objects as a value.

Objects have the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "key": "param1",
    "val": "value1"
  },
  {
    "key": "param2",
    "val": "value2"
  },
  {
    "key": "param3",
    "val": "value3"
  }
]
```

| someColumn | colName |
| --- | --- |
| text | `[{key: "param1", val: "value1"}, {key: "param2", val: "value2"}, {key: "param3", val: "value3"}]` |

When I do:

```
df.withColumn("exploded", explode(col("colName")))
```

I get

| someColumn | exploded |
| --- | --- |
| text | `{key: "param1", val: "value1"}` |
| text | `{key: "param2", val: "value2"}` |
| text | `{key: "param3", val: "value3"}` |

Then I do next:

`df.select("*", "exploded.*").drop("exploded")`

I get this:

| someColumn | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| text | param1 | value1 |
| text | param2 | value2 |
| text | param3 | value3 |

I understand why I get such result but I need to get other structure.

I want to get next result:

| someColumn | param1 | param2 | param3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| text | value1 | value2 | value3 |

Maybe do I have to transform array of Object[key, value] to Map and then to transform Map to Columns? What is the sequence of transformations I have to do?

Comment: Try pivot to DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you explode your dataset, you can:

```
df = df.groupBy("someColumn").pivot("exploded.key").agg(first("exploded.val"))
```

This is created from the above statement:

```
+----------+------+------+------+
|someColumn|param1|param2|param3|
+----------+------+------+------+
|text      |value1|value2|value3|
+----------+------+------+------+
```

which is what you like!

Comment: Yeah, it works. What do you think about another solution that I came up with?

Comment: If the keys are fixed, than your solution is good. But you want to avoid .collect() as that triggers an action already, for big data processing, I think you should go with pivot or a solution that does not include actions

Answer (score 0):

I found one more solution:

```
val mappedDF = df
      .select(
        $"*",
        col("ColName").getField("key").as("keys"),
        col("ColName").getField("val").as("values")
      )
      .drop("ColName")
      .select(
        $"*",
        map_from_arrays($"keys", $"values").as("ColName")
      )

    val keysDF = mappedDF.select(explode(map_keys($"CalName"))).distinct()
    val keys = keysDF.collect().map(f=>f.get(0))
    val keyCols = keys.map(f=> col("CalName").getItem(f).as(f.toString))
    mappedDF.select(col("*") +: keyCols:_*).drop("CalName")
```

This solution work faster than `pivot`. But I'm not sure that it's the best solution.

BTW If we know list of keys and this list is fixed, this solution becomes more faster because we don't have to get list of keys from DF.

I wrote more universal code when we need to group by a few cols. In my post I simplified example for understanding purposes.