# Pyspark Transform Key value Pairs into Row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
[{
    key=Username,
    value=
},
{
    key=Email,
    value=
},
{
    key=Id,
    value=
},
{
    key=Organization,
    value=
},
{
    key=Role,
    value=
},
{
    key=Address,
    value=
},
{
    key=Component,
    value=
},
{
    key=Reason,
    value=
},
{
    key=Region,
    value=
}]

root
|-- headers: array
|    |-- element: struct
|    |    |-- key: string
|    |    |-- value: string
|-- id: string
```

My JSON Data looks like above, I need to tranform into this into single row, with Key as Column Name and Value as data.

My data need to have following column:
Username , Email, Id, Organization, Role, Address, Component, Reason, Region

Attached is the schema.

I tried to use explode which converts the key value pair into rows and the data looks like following,

```
--------------+-----------------------+----------+
|headers                                                                                      |id        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-----------------------+----------+
|{Username, }                                                                                    |8239|
|{Email, }                                                                                       |8239|
|{Id, }                                                                                          |8239|
|{Organization, }                                                                                |8239|
|{Role, []}                                                                                      |8239|
|{Address, 9}                                                                            |8239|
|{Component, 9}                                                                             |8239|
|{Reason, 9}                                                                                |8239|
|{Region, 9999}                                                                    |8239|
```

Comment: [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode)

Comment: @Steven, Yes I just updated the question, I used explode but it gives me rows rather than columns, I need to use pivot as well to group by ID, but I am not aware of how to achieve that in Spark. I was able to flatten this data in Athena(Presto using SQL query), trying to replicate same in Spark.

Comment: Try `select('id', 'headers.*')` after explode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inline_outer` function to flatten `array<struct>` column, then apply `groupby` and `pivot` to get desired result.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import first
df.selectExpr("id", "inline_outer(headers)").\
    groupby("id").\
    pivot("key").\
    agg(first("value")).\
    show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: ``` 
df = df.groupBy("id").pivot("headers.key").agg(first("headers.value"))``` this worked for me, I didnt try your solution, I refered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73190802/spark-how-to-convert-array-of-objects-with-fields-key-value-into-columns-with-k